# GNU Global + ggtags and helm + helm+gtags

Tags: helm, development, gtags, global-mode

In http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#orgheadline2 which is about "Prerequisite"

> - Or, helm + helm-gtags.

What does "Or" imply as the alternative to the combination "helm + helm+gtags"?

Is the alternative

- GNU Global
- GNU Global + ggtags

What are the relations between GNU Global and helm?
Are GNU Global and helm  alternatives to each other?

ggtags is a frontend of GNU Global, and is helm-gtags a frontend of helm?

What should I install according to the link?

Is it okay to install both combinations GNU Global + ggtags and helm + helm+gtags, and to use them both in the future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Hope this clears up the confusion ..

---

### Non-emacs software

- [GNU Global (`gtags` + `global` executables)](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/) - A software for generating tags, like [Universal `ctags`](https://ctags.io/). *I actually use [`gtags`](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/) for binary database generation but have configured it to use [`ctags`](https://ctags.io/) as backend because [`ctags`](https://ctags.io/) supports tag parsing for many more languages.*

**It is mandatory to install GNU Global if you want to use either of the below 2 packages.**

---

### Emacs packages

- [`ggtags`](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags) - A front-end for accessing the `gtags`-generated tags.
- [`helm-gtags`](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-gtags) - **Another** front-end for accessing the `gtags`-generated tags, but this one uses an alternative list-completion mechanism called [`helm`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm). So you will need to install `helm` for `helm-gtags` to work (or it will be auto-installed if you use the Emacs `package.el` to install packages). *If you haven't used `helm`, then it's safe to say that `ggtags` will work just fine for you.*

---

### Installation combinations

1. GNU Global + `ggtags`
2. GNU Global + `helm` + `helm-gtags`
3. As `ggtags` and `helm-gtags` are independent, you can even have both of the above combinations installed and see what setup works the best for you.

Comment: thanks. In "have configured it to use ctags as backend because ctags supports tag parsing for many more languages",  do you mean that ctags is better than gtags in all the cases? How do you configure gtabs to use ctags as backend?

Comment: another question: what are the relations between ctags and GNU Global  and gtags?

Comment: Those are all very broad questions. I would suggest that you first read its [manual online](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html). [This section](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Plug_002din) of the manual explains how to build `gtags` with `ctags` configured as the backend. *PS: Exuberant ctags is now Universal ctags.*